# Flight of a baseball in heavy rain

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile, drag

Hello physics stack exchange, the first thing I'll say is that I am a statistician by trade, not a physicist. I want to predict the distance of a baseball given its initial velocity, launch angle, spin, and weather variables. Currently I am fitting a generalized additive model (GAM) using these covariates, but I think this modeling part is relatively unimportant.

I am having trouble understanding this home run in particular: https://sporty-clips.mlb.com/5bc1ef2f-761f-447e-bd0e-312483b6239f.mp4. The batted ball was hit at 107 mph, 40 degrees, and in air having 0.0738 lbs/ft^3 density. It traveled a total distance of 463'. My model is under-predicting it vastly at a mere 390'.

As you can see in the video, it was raining pretty hard. To calculate the air density at the time of 0.0738 lbs/ft^3, I use the temperature of 72.2 F, altitude of 130', sea level pressure of 1012.8 hPa, and relative humidity of 83.86%. I'm guessing that the high humidity plus all the water vapor in the air meant the density of the air was lower than average, helping the ball travel quite far. There was not much wind at all when the ball was hit.

So my question is: how might rain like this affect the flight of the baseball? Furthermore, if you have any modeling suggestions, I'm open to those too.

Your thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: "my model is having trouble..." What is "your model"? Can you write it down rather than giving a link to a video.

Comment: "So my question is: how might rain like this affect the flight of the baseball?" Lots of different ways. There's a bunch of little impulses downward (or in whatever direction the rain is going). There's added mass due to water sticking onto the ball. There a lot of different stuff that could happen.

Comment: Interesting question. For air foils I think generally the drag increases in the rain, but lift also depends on the boundary layer and how the boundary layer separates. The reason I would guess drag increases is that you displace both air and water so it is a denser medium. But if the ball is spinning then there is perhaps some lift…

Comment: "Currently I am fitting a generalized additive model (GAM)..." This doesn't really tell us anything about the model. Are you even applying any physical reasoning, or just trying to fit an elephant?

Comment: @hft I guess trying to fit an elephant. I can try to look at some projectile motion equations, though I avoided doing so because it's completely foreign territory and I thought I could obtain reasonable results quickly by chucking a flexible model at the data.

Comment: I do not see that you have accounted for the rotational spin of the ball, which the trajectory of a baseball is profoundly affected by.  So much so that the spin of the ball could absolutely account for those kinds of errors.  Watch a hard-hit foul ball curve left or right.  Also be careful about making any assumptions about negligible wind.  It’s also a huge Input and in a stadium it’s not unusual at all for the surface wind to be very different from the wind a few hundred feet up.  Nor would it be unusual for that wind to have a vertical component, blowing over the lip of a stadium.